# MySQL trigger, view, separate table, or on-the-fly calculation for loyalty points?

Tags: mysql, database-design, view, triggers

What is the least resource-intensive way to calculate a sum of points from two tables? The total point tally is calculated by adding points from a table `points` and subtracting points from a table `points_redeemed`.

`points`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS points(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user__id INT,
    tx__id INT,
    points INT
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

`points_redeemed`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS points_redeemed(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user__id INT,
    points INT
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

(Both tables above are heavily simplified.)

`points` is populated upon a transaction (recorded in a different table). When transaction values are changed or voided, the corresponding row in `points` is updated as well.

`points_redeemed` is populated when user redeems their accumulated points for a reward.

Use cases:

- show stats to user and admin: total, redeemed, and unredeemed points
- check unredeemed points upon user-initiated redeem request

The options I've came up with are:

**a) Triggers.**
Create a table `points_sum` with one row per user.id and add three triggers:

- on insert into `points`
- on update of `points`
- on insert into `points_redeemed`

I've heard that MySQL triggers are not that performant though, so I'm simply not sure if this is a good idea.

**b) View.**
Create a view that calculates `points.points` - `points_redeemed.points`. Not sure if this is any better than just doing it on the fly.

**c) Sum table.**
Create a table `points_sum` and update it per separate query each time `points` and `points_redeemed` is inserted into and updated. This feels like the least effective way, but then again I could be wrong and it might be the best way.

**d) On the fly.**
Query points from both tables on the fly and calculate the difference. This is the easiest and probably the most accurate way, but it can potentially clog up the pipes a lot when the tables grow in size. Then again, are any of the other options any better in that regard?

**Edit:** These are the current on-the-fly queries.

First, a very straight-forward query from `points_redeemed`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    points_redeemed
WHERE   user__id = 1
```

Second, the `points` table is queried:

```
(
SELECT  p.*,
        tx.*

FROM    points p
        INNER JOIN tx ON p.tx__id = tx.id

WHERE   p.user__id = '1'
  AND   p.tx_is_external IS NULL

ORDER BY p.date DESC
)

UNION

(
SELECT  p.*,
        tx.*

FROM    points p
        INNER JOIN tx_external tx ON p.tx__id = tx.id

WHERE   p.user__id = '1'
  AND   p.tx_is_external = '1'

ORDER BY p.date DESC
)
```

(There are several named columns SELECTed that I abbrieviated as * here. In the second query, about 40 columns are fetched per row.)

After this, I'm looping through both result sets and adding/subtracting points on the app layer.

My worry is that the two separate queries, and the joins in the second query, might "clog the pipes" when the tx tables grow in size (and the points table too). That's why I'm trying to figure out a better way that will save resources at runtime.

The more I think about it though... transactions and points inserts will probably happen a lot more frequently than a user looking up their current point status. In that scenario, a trigger would probably have the opposite effect.

I'd appreciate any kind of insight. Thank you!

Comment: Do not use MyISAM !

Comment: Thanks Rick - why not?

Comment: MyISAM is slower, not crash safe, being deprecated, etc.  Also use `NOT NULL` and `UNSIGNED` and smaller datatypes than `INT` when appropriate.  Is the `PRIMARY KEY` the only index?  (I'm worried that you have over-simplified the schema.)

Comment: `points.tx__id` is `UNIQUE`, as each tx can only have one points row. Other than that, there are no other indexes. Good catch re: `UNSIGNED` - I will add that. Re: MyISAM, I will read up on that following your advice, thanks for the heads up. Do you happen to have any recommendation about the question too? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: If `tx__id` is unique, it could be the `PRIMARY KEY`, and you could get rid of the surrogate `id`.

Comment: How many updates per second?  (That will lead to advice on triggers vs IODKU vs ...)

Comment: Hard to say since there's no reliable historic data right now. I'd say between 10 and 50 per inserts per second during peaks. Updates will happen much less frequently - only when a transaction is voided or so... maybe once per day max. And points_redeemed will also probably not happen more than 1-5x per day.

Comment: On `tx__id` - I said that too fast / incompletely. There are two possible "tx" tables and `points` has an additional column that references one of them. So it's actually `UNIQUE (tx__id, tx__table)`. Sorry about the misinformation!

Comment: Let's see the queries that might "clog the pipes".  They may be critical in the choice of design.

Comment: I added the queries to my OP. I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

- `WHERE   user__id = 1` needs `INDEX(user__id)` on the table.
- `( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... ) UNION ( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... )` will not have a particular order; do you need to move the `ORDER BY` outside?
- `tx` and `tx_external` need `id` to be indexed (`PRIMARY KEY`?)
- Did you really want `UNION DISTINCT`?  That's the default.  `UNION ALL` is faster.

Fix those, then see if you still need to discuss triggers, etc.